# how to do vi search and replace within a range in sublime text

Tags: regex, search, vim, replace, sublimetext2

I enabled [vintage](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/vintage.html) mode on sublime text.. but there are some important vim commands that are lacking.. so let's say I want to do a search and replace like so

```
:10,25s/searchedText/toReplaceText/gc
```

so I wanna search `searchedText` and replace it with `toReplaceText` from lines `10` to `25` and be prompted every time (ie yes/no)..

how do I do this with Sublime Text? everytime I hit `:` it gives me this funny menu.. any way around that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you so much would like to see vim in action, try the other way around; ie enable sublime stuff in vim.

Here are 2 links that might come in handy:
[subvim](https://github.com/fatih/subvim) and [vim multiple cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors) (Which is one amazing feature in sublime that lacks in native vim).

Hope that gets you creative ;)

Comment: subvim is fantastic, highly recommend it.

Comment: @MattGreer Does subvim provide me all vim features?

Comment: @moyen subvim has not been supported/updated in a long time now. I recommend just building your own vim setup. If you do JavaScript/TypeScript, then Oni is also a good choice: http://onivim.io

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately vintage mode does not understand ranges. The best way I know how to do this is with incremental search:

1. highlight the first occurrence of `searchedText` on line 10
2. hit <kbd>cmnd</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> to have Sublime find the next occurence
3. If you you want the next occurrence ignored, hit <kbd>cmnd</kbd>/<kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd>
4. Once you have highlighted all the occurrences, you can replace them all at once, as Sublime has left cursors behind on every occurrence you opted in on.

Comment: also even jumping to line doesn't work right? ie if I hit `:` it gives me that weird menu again.. the only way I can jump to a line number on sublime text is by `CTRL-G` right?

Comment: You can go to a line with :<number> just like vi. That menu does accept some of the same commands as vi, but not many.

Comment: that's odd.. if i hit `:` I get that menu.. but if I enter a line number other than `0` or `$` (For `BOF`, `EOF`, respectively) it does nothing.. but if i hit `ctrl g`, I get the same menu.. and it takes me to any line I want.. any idea why that happens (and how I can correct it)?

Answer (score 2):

[VintageEx](https://github.com/SublimeText/VintageEx) gives you a Vim-like command-line where you can *at least* perform substitutions. Well, that's how far I went when trying it. I don't know how extended the subset of Vim commands it implements is but I'd guess that it's not as large as the original and, like with Vintage, probably different and unsettling enough to keep a relatively experienced Vimmer out.

Anyway, I just tried it again and indeed you can more or less do the kind of substitution you are looking for, which instantly makes ST *a lot* more useful:

```
:3,5s/foo/bar/g
:.,5s/bar/foo/g
:,5/foo/bar/g
:,+5/bar/foo/g
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't support the `/c` flag.

Comment: vintageEx also solved the `:` problem i mentioned in the comments [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16248167/766570)

Answer (score 1):

a plugin named `vintageous` offers more features including search function. It's available in `package control`

Answer (score 0):

although this question is answered.. i figured this would add some value

the full functionality of vi search/replace is possible with the [ruby mine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/quickstart/index.html) IDE, once you install the [ideavim](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?ruby&id=164) plugin. The idea is perfect for ruby on rails by the way.